# Talend - Null after tAggregateRow

Tags: null, talend

I have made a structure like this to check the highest loan amount per Customer ID given their agreements.

```
tOracleInput (2) --> tMap --> tOracleOutput --> tAggregateRow --> tMap --> tOracleOutput
```

my first tOracleInput is where list of Customers and on my second tOracleInput is where agreements and  loan amount are stored, then I used Tmap to map customer to their Agreements. (this is ok - it gets all the info), then I store those info on my tOracleOutput (this is OK- it gets all the info) then I use tAggregateRow to Group by Customer ID and Get the Max loanAmount of each Customer ID. So, I will expect 1 loanAmount per Customer ID. It did so. (but other info became null) Then, I map that record on my last tOracleOutput with all other information like, interest, name and others.... But, it only stores the Customer ID and loanAmount.

I have the following fields and it is mapped from tOracleOutput before the AggregateROw to the last tOracleOutput

```
Customer_ID ->  Customer_ID
Customer_Name -> Customer_Name
loanAmount   -> loanAmount
loanInterest -> loanInterest
delStatus  -> delStatus
```

but it only stores:
    Customer_ID |null|10000|null|null

why other information became null after tAggregateRow, is there a way to get all info that I need after determining the max?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to be including screenshots of your job layout and configuration of key components (in this case the tAggregateRow and tMaps) otherwise it becomes very difficult to help you. If you linked to a few external images someone here would edit them inline for you and you'll likely get upvotes on your question and will be able to do it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is null because you need to  specify an aggregate operation for the other fields too. You can use "first element", for exemple, to take the first value encountered in the input data.

Comment: What I just did is to add a tSortRow then get First w/ tAggregateRow. Thank You for the Suggestion.